# How can retrive all TCP UDP opened ports?

Tags: c, sockets, port

I need to make a custom port scanner that scan only opened TCP and UDP ports. I'm working in standard C with sockets. For the moment i retrieve all ports in a range i set.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int scanPort(struct hostent *hostaddr,int port){
    char responce[1024];
    char *message="checking port";
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    int socket_d;
    int rval;
    socket_d = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(socket_d == -1)
    {
        perror("Socket()\n");
        return errno;
    }
    memset(&server_address,0,sizeof(server_address));

    server_address.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port=htons(port);

    memcpy(&server_address.sin_addr,hostaddr->h_addr,hostaddr->h_length);

    rval = connect(socket_d,(struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    if(rval == -1)
    {
        close(socket_d);    
        return 0;
    }else{
        close(socket_d);
        return 1;
    }

}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 4){
        printf("Exemplu: ./portscanner <adresa_ip> <port_pornire> <port_oprire> \n");
        return (EINVAL);
    }

    int startPort;
    int endPort;
    int port;
    struct hostent *host_address;

    host_address = gethostbyname( argv[1] );
    startPort = atoi(argv[2]);
    endPort = atoi(argv[3]);

    for(port = startPort;port<=endPort;port++)
    {
        if(scanPort(host_address,port)==1){
            printf("Port %d is open\n",port);
        }
    }
}
```

In the example you can see how i tried to resolve this problem. But i don't see a method to  check only the TCP and UDP ports. Please help me with this.

Regards,
Badea Sorin!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plenty ways to do it. I recommend you to install `nmap` and read the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/nmap.1.html).
Many scan methods are implemented there and described in the manual.

You can also refer to the source code if you need more details.

Good luck.

Comment: i need something native. i don't have root access where i need to run this tool

Comment: You don't need to run nmap. You just need to read the manual. If you cannot install it then use online manual from my answer.

Comment: oh i got it. but i'm kind of noobie. hope that i find this userfull